# How to select user type letters in Search Delegate?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I developed search using search delegate. when user search I bold user type letters. But it's working only if user start to type with beginning otherwise bold letters wrong.

```
RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: suggestList[index].d.substring(0, query.length),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: suggestList[index].d.substring(query.length),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ])),
```

[image]

Comment: I don't exaclty understand what you want, but I see that you added `fontWeight: FontWeight.bold` for the first `TextSpan` and not for the second. Maybe add it to the second too may answer your question !

Comment: I edited my question..you can see my issue... I typed **room** but highlight letters wrong

Comment: It's normal it highlights the wrong letters, because in your `substring` function you gave the value `0` to the `startIndex`, which it will always start from the beginning. What you need is to know where your word, in the result search start (the index), and then give it to `startIndex`. PS: `String substring(int startIndex, [int endIndex]);`